# Ajax request - determine current wordpress page in functions.php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've tried to determine the current page in functions.php with an **if (is_home())** function, because I only want to run the specific ajax request on my homepage, but it always returns false and if I request the current URI, it says **/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php,** the URI I actually request in my JS Ajax function.

So how can I only request my current page instead of the Ajax request?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Better detect the current page *before* sending the Ajax request, no?

Answer (score 0):

In the javascript

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

Then you can pass it with the rest of your data to the php function.